# Value of guessed word doesn't add up to the assigned variable in while loop PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm quite new to coding and I'm trying to write a dictionary which checks if I know translations to some words. So far it's been good, but I have a small problem which I'm sure it's trivial but don't know how to improve the code.

When I get a word right it's supposed to be added in the variable 'right' but since it's in a while loop it only does that once and when I get another word right it doesn't add up. How can I fix that?

```
for key, value in words:
    right = 0
    print ('What does', key, 'mean ?')
    given_meaning = input ('It means: ')
    while True:

        if given_meaning == value:
            right += 1
            x = Decimal(right/dict_len)*100
            final_number = round(x, 2)
            print ('Yes! You got it right!')
            print ('You know', final_number ,'% of the words.')
            break

        if given_meaning != value:
            print ('Unfortunately, this means:', value, '.' )
            print ('You know ', final_number ,'% of the words.')
            break
```

It constantly shows the result of getting one word right.
Can you help?

Comment: Well, you only ask the user once for input... what did you expect to happen?

Comment: You reset `right = 0` on every loop iteration, move that line outside the loop.

Comment: thank you so much! I couldn't find the mistake but it works now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
right = 0
for key, value in words:
print ('What does', key, 'mean ?')
given_meaning = input ('It means: ')
while True:

    if given_meaning == value:
        right += 1
        x = Decimal(right/dict_len)*100
        final_number = round(x, 2)
        print ('Yes! You got it right!')
        print ('You know', final_number ,'% of the words.')
        break

    if given_meaning != value:
        print ('Unfortunately, this means:', value, '.' )
        print ('You know ', final_number ,'% of the words.')
        break
```

That should do the trick. The way you currently have it, you are setting `right = 0` with every iteration through the for loop.